# How to make a remove frame script in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, frames

I am making websites I refer to from my site load up in a frame (similar to google images). But I also want to give users the ability to break out of that frame. Like with google image's "Remove Frame" link at the bottom right corner of their frame. How can I do this possiblyusing Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
top.location = "URL of framed page";
```

Alternatively, you can make a regular `<a>` tag with `target="_top"`.

Comment: I need it to be the other way around. This closes the referred site and takes the user to the frame's page. I want the frame to close and the user to be taken to the refereed site.

Comment: If your code is in the framed page, you can write `top.location = location`.