# Java Response Redirect from https to http

Tags: jsp, redirect

Hi I have a small Problem.

I have a website, wherein i'm using some payment gateways.

After payment the payment gateway returns me to my website, in a way that the URL remains the same. So i see the content of my website but i see the url of the payment gateway.[How is this achieved?]

Secondaly, when i see the content of my website(which is my jsp) in this jsp i am doing a redirect, which redirects me to the target page but the url is not updated in the address bar even when i write the complete url http://

Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The payment gateway must use a frame or iframe and set the URL of the only visible frame to your website URL. So the main page is the page of the payment gateway, and this page only contains a frame or iframe which loads your website.

Comment: hmm Perfect that answer stands valid i guess. :-) but response.SendRedirect() ? works only in the current frame? or so ?

Comment: Yes. Each frame is independant from the other frames. That why when you click on a link in the main frame of the java api doc, for example, the two frames on the left are not refreshed. That behavior can be checked by adding a `target` attribute on the links.

Comment: But how can i handle that in Redirect :( any idea .. How can i change it in Response.sendRedirect :(

Comment: Check with the gateway if it can avoid this framing, or add JavaScript to your page to change the location. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618077/how-to-make-a-remove-frame-script-in-javascript